# Hadoop mapreduce getMapOutput failed

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Current setup:
- Hadoop 0.20.2-cdh3u3
- Hbase Version 0.90.4-cdh3u3
- Jetty-6.1.14
- Running on VM (Debian Squeeze)

Problem appears during mapreduce process on Hbase table. On the Reduce phase it crashes every time at the very same point with these logs in tasktracker.log:

```
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: getMapOutput(attempt_201205290717_0001_m_000010_0,3) failed:
org.mortbay.jetty.EofException

WARN org.mortbay.log: Committed before 410 getMapOutput(attempt_201205290717_0001_m_000010_0,3) failed :
org.mortbay.jetty.EofException

ERROR org.mortbay.log: /mapOutput
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
```

Hoping anyone faced the same or similar problem before, looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue here.

On my cluster, this happens on all slaves (datanode & tasttrackers) except for one, which results in the general reduce process to first progress very slowly and at a certain point in a reroll of the reduce progress so far due to some error. the reduce process then starts all over again: the job never finishes.

There is an open major issue in the bugtracker. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-5

Let us hope, it will be fixed some day, but at the very moment, i can not use my hadoop program with huge files > 3 GB at all. In my case i hope, i can fix it by additional data cleaning and more efficient data structures (trove, fastutils), so the problem doesnt occur at all, but honestly, this feels kind of like the wrong approach here. Not to do those smaller tweaks was the main reason starting with hadoop anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The Jetty `EOFException` is observed when the reduce Task prematurely closes a connection to a jetty server. Restart the tasktrackers and run the job again. See if it works for you.